# Layout diagrams

Tags: margins

I want to create some layout diagrams for a latex talk for students.

However I do not want to have any information about the sizes included and do not want any dashed lines (as in the `layout(s)` packages)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[]{layout}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}\mbox{}
\layout
\end{document}
```

With the `layouts` package I can customize some more things, but I still can not get rid of the sizes and the margin has no full height with a 'notes' bock which I do not understand.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{layouts}

\begin{document}
\oddpagelayoutfalse
\twocolumnlayoutfalse
\drawdimensionsfalse
\printheadingsfalse
\currentpage
\marginparswitchtrue 
\pagedesign
\end{document}
```

There is also the `showframe` package, but that is a bit to simple in the shown layout.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[texcoord,gridunit=cm]{showframe}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}\mbox{}
\end{document}
```

the `geometry` package also has the possibility to show the layout, but I want to compare non-geometry layouts (book standard) with geometry layouts. So i need something that works even without that package.

In the end I want to crop the pdfs and include these as images in a talk.

Comment: Why don't you draw them in a graphics program? Or use tikz? Or do you need the exact lengths of the "current" document?

Comment: Indeed, I require the exact length of the current document. I just dont want the length or addional lines to be printed.

Comment: You cannot show output of LaTeX on this site but you can generate it yourself, take a screenshot of it, crop it and include it as an image.

Comment: If you load `\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}` the class settings are not touched.

Comment: Yes, but that is not much more information or different in layout than \usepackage[texcoord,gridunit=cm]{showframe}, which I have used now.

Comment: If you want to showcase "different layouts", I would suggest using the [`geometry` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) for each in a separate file (using the `\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}` option as specified by @egreg). Then include the necessary layout pages in a final document using [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages). This way you have freedom over apparent multiple (and likely different) layouts, all contained within one document. Alternatively, `geometry` also provides `\newgeometry{...}` for mid-document changes. Is this what you're after?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the picture drawn by **layouts** is good for you, we can patch the `\drawpage` command so that it doesn't print the table with the values of the various parameters:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{layouts,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\drawpage}{\ifl@ytempif\begin{center}}{\iffalse\begin{center}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\oddpagelayoutfalse
\twocolumnlayoutfalse
\drawdimensionsfalse
\printheadingsfalse
\currentpage
\marginparswitchtrue
\pagedesign
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is not only the paramters. Also the dashed line (I do not even understand its purpose) and the Note box are unwanted. Further I do not understand why the margin box is only displayed at the bottom of the page and does not span the total body height. Anyway I used now the showframe package.